# UWP ListView scroll bar not selectable in touch mode

Tags: c#, touch, win-universal-app, uwp

I have a simple `ListView` in a Universal Windows App. It scrolls just fine both on a touch-enabled device and on my local machine. On the touch device I would like to be able to tap and drag the scroll bar thumb in order to quickly scroll through the list (same as you would get clicking and dragging the scroll thumb with a mouse). But, when I try to select the scroll bar thumb it does not work; the thumb is not selectable.

At first I thought the scroll thumb was just too small, so I fiddled with the default style of `ScrollBar` to increase the width. Then I tried tweaking other values in the default `ScrollViewer` style, like the `ScrollingIndicatorMode` and `ScrollingIndicatorStates` so that they would always use `MouseIndicator`, and making sure all `IsHitTestVisible` are `True`. To no avail.

It seems like there must be something in the default styles that allows this but I can't find it through trial and error, and no where in the MSDN docs appears to address this styling.

Is this doable in touch mode?

Comment: I have similar issues recently, not only the thumb but the "HorizontalLargeIncrease" repeatButton doesn't work with touch mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity's sake I want to post my work around which actually turned out not being quite as difficult as I thought and looks really good now.

The basic idea is to use a `Slider` control (has a `Thumb` that is select-able, drag-able, and moves along a track) with a vertical orientation and to sync the `Slider`'s `Value` property (which changes when dragged) to the `ListView`'s `ScrollIntoView` method so you can scroll the `ListView` as the `Slider` `Thumb` is dragged. Vice-versa (move the `Slider` `Thumb` when the `ListView` scrolls normally) is also required for a clean, seamless experience. I have some code sample below to get you started (not everything is there to work right away). In addition, edit the `Slider`'s default `Style` template to make it look exactly like a scroll bar (and even even add a tooltip to display the current value when dragging).

Note: I'm using WinRTXamlToolkit in code-behind to traverse the `VisualTree` easily.

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private bool _isScroll = false;
    private bool _isSlide = false;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var vm = new ViewModel();
        vm.ValueChanged += LetterSliderValueChanged;
        DataContext = vm;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Bring list items into view on the screen based on the value (letter) of the slider
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The view model to bring into view</param>
    private void LetterSliderValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isScroll) return;
        if (sender == null) return;

        _isSlide = true;

        ListView?.ScrollIntoView(sender, ScrollIntoViewAlignment.Leading);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Update the position of the slider when the ListView is scrolling from a normal touch
    /// </summary>
    private void ScrollViewerViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isSlide)
        {
            _isSlide = false;
            return;
        }

        _isScroll = true;

        var scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
        var scrollBars = scrollViewer.GetDescendantsOfType<ScrollBar>();
        var verticalBar = scrollBars.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Orientation == Orientation.Vertical);

        // Normalize the scales to move the slider thumb in sync with scrolling
        var sliderTotal = LetterSlider.Maximum - LetterSlider.Minimum;
        var barTotal = verticalBar.Maximum - verticalBar.Minimum;
        var barPercent = verticalBar.Value / barTotal;
        LetterSlider.Value = (barPercent * sliderTotal) + LetterSlider.Minimum;

        _isScroll = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add the slider method to the ListView's ScrollViewer Viewchanged event
    /// </summary>
    private void ListViewLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listview = sender as ListView;
        if (listview == null) return;
        var scrollViewer = listview.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
        scrollViewer.ViewChanged -= ScrollViewerViewChanged;
        scrollViewer.ViewChanged += ScrollViewerViewChanged;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Slider x:Name="LetterSlider" Orientation="Vertical"
            Value="{Binding SliderValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            Maximum="{Binding MaxSliderLetter, Mode=OneTime}" 
            Minimum="{Binding MinSliderLetter, Mode=OneTime}" 
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Slider.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
        </Slider.RenderTransform>
</Slider>
```

View Model:

```
    //Method to update the ListView to show items based on the letter of the slider
    public RoutedEventHandler ValueChanged;

    public int SliderValue
    {
        get { return _sliderValue; }
        set
        {
            _sliderValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SliderValue");

            char letter = (char)_sliderValue;
            var items = ItemsGroup.FirstOrDefault(i => (char)i.Key == letter);
            if (items == null) return;
            ValueChanged(items.FirstOrDefault(), new RoutedEventArgs());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is this doable in touch mode?

AFAIK, this is not possible currently. The scroll event of `ScrollBar` can only be triggered by scrolling the content or moving the `Thumb` by mouse input.

This is by design, but on the touch device if we want to quickly scroll through the list, we just quickly swipe one item for a short distance, the `ListView` will firstly speed up the scrolling and then slow down and finally stop. Other controls which contain a `ScrollViewer` behave the same, in the viewport(content of `ScrollViewer`) when in touch device, moving the thumb is not work, to speed up the scrolling, you can only give quick swipe gesture on the viewport.

Our suggestion is that you may submit a request to add this new features for developing through the Windows Feedback tool.

Comment: Inertial scrolling (quick swipe) isn't an accurate way to traverse a large list. If you have a large list of names (contacts for example), it is a much better experience to be able to grasp the scroll bar and browse alphabetically (a la Android). I will submit a request.

Comment: Grace Feng, I've accepted my own answer that contains a viable workaround, but I wanted to say thanks again for confirming there is no built-in functionality for this.